# Is there a way to find out to which projects a GCP service account has access to?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts

It seems I can't just write the same question from the title in the body. Because it wouldn't meet the quality standards.

Comment: Do you want to know on which project a service account has been granted? If so, are that other projects, in an organisation? Or totally random/outside your org?

Comment: The service account is in our project. A client wanted to grant our service account permissions in his project. But we don't know the name/id of his project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run: `gcloud projects list --impersonate-service-account=<your-service-account-email-address>`

This requires Cloud Resource Manager API (cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com) to be enabled and resourcemanager.projects.list permission for the service account.

The flag is very self-explanatory: It runs the commands as the given service account instead of your configured credentials.

Comment: It worked! Thank you. First I got error-message:  `Failed to impersonate <...>. Make sure the account that's trying to impersonate it has access to the service account itself and the "roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator" role.` So I had to grant myself the serviceAccountTokenCreator IAM-role on the project and owner-role on the service-account. Then it worked.